# How can I expose the AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE to docker container that runs on GitLab runner with Kubernetes executor

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am running java application that tries access to AWS s3 bucket on a docker container with AWS Java SDK in order to load credentials from WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider.

I am running that docker on Gitlab runner with Kubernetes executor.

I created a job that runs a docker container.

```
myJod:
  image: docker:19.03.12
  script:
    - all relevant installations ...
    - docker-compose build
    - docker-compose up
```

On the runner itself, I can run aws commands and get s3 buckets. Also, I have access to $AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE from the runner.

But when I run a docker container on the runner, the docker can't access $AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE.

I got following error:

```
com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain - Unable to load credentials from WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: Unable to locate specified web identity token file.
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Make $AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE available to container via a environment variable. Check here
 https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers